# What is the Biblical Basis for the Closure of the Canon?

Tags: biblical-basis, bible, canon

What is the Biblical Basis for a Closed Canon?

Comment: Related : [How do Sola Scriptura defenders have a 'list' of scripture . . .  etc ?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/89229/how-do-sola-scriptura-defenders-have-a-list-of-scripture-since-the-list-isnt)

Comment: Why closed? I drafted an answer. Here's the outline:
While there is no agreed-upon scriptural basis for the closing of Scripture, here are two verses that are sometimes cited.

For the OT, the penultimate verses of the Book of Ecclesiastes:

> And furthermore, my son, be admonished: of making many books there is
> no end; and much study is a weariness of the flesh. This is the end of
> the matter; all hath been heard: Fear God, and keep his commandments;
> for this is the whole duty of man. (Ecc. 12:12-13)

Comment: For the New Testament, the Book of Revelation 22:18 contains an admonition which is sometimes applied to the whole Bible:

> I testify unto every man that heareth the words of the prophecy of
> this book, If any man shall add unto them, God shall add unto him the
> plagues which are written in this book: 

{NOTE: I do not think these verses should be understood as closing the canon... but people do use them (esp. Rev. 22) as an argument to that effect.}

Comment: I see now that the question was basically asked/answered earlier. I am removing my vote to re-open.