# Is Hell in the OT? Chronologically, when was the concept of Hell first mentioned in the Bible?

Tags: bible, old-testament, hell

Chronologically, when was the concept of Hell first mentioned in the Bible?

Is it mentioned in the Old Testament, or is it only in the New?

Assuming a standard consensus view of when each book of the bible was written, which book of the bible contains the oldest reference to it?  Put another way, if the bible were arranged according to date of composition, when would the first reference to Hell be?

Comment: Are there many concepts of hell? I think the OP means when is the idea of wicked dying in hell is first portrayed in the Bible @curiousdannii

Comment: @CRags: There are a few words translated as "hell" in English translations of the Bible. So, the OP needs to explicitly state which one he is concerned about. Does he mean "hell" as in the grave, or "hell" as in the place of eternal punishment?

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 Why not both? There's only one or two others, right?

Comment: @fredsbend I think there are too many possibilities for it to be clear enough. The grave as a nonconscious place? As a conscious place? As a place of punishment, or a waiting place? As a real place, or symbolic? Does he mean the valley outside Jerusalem? The Jewish place of the dead? The Greek realm of the dead?

Comment: Why not google "bible verses on hell" or something like that? You'd be able to refine your question.

Comment: @JimG. Because some questions require more research than that. I actually *do* Google all (yes, all) questions I ask before I ask them. If I find something relevant, then I may not ask, or I may change the question I was going to ask. This site isn't Christianity.LMGTFY. If you hover over the up- and down-vote buttons on questions, they mention "research effort." The idea is that if you ask a question, you've already done some research and not asking us to do *all* of it for you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a verse search question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a verse search question.

Comment: Why did you remove the section that explains what you mean by the word "hell"? As the question stands now, it is wide open and will never be reopened. ¶ Many denominations have their own specific doctrine as to what the word means, ranging from the trivial, "the grave where dead bodies are buried and left to rot", to the fantastic, "a place where immortal souls are tormented forever". For the former the answer would be [Genesis 37:35](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/gen/37/35/s_37035), where the Hebrew word is translated as "grave".

Comment: @RayButterworth That section was too verbose and it wasn't improving the reopen odds.

Answer (score 6):

The concept of Hell was known by the Israelites as Sheol. It is mentioned by Jacob when he is told of his son Joseph's death. He states in Genesis 37:36 that "I shall go down to my son a mourner unto Sheol.

Sheol is a Hebrew word of uncertain origin. It is a synonym of shahat which means pit or destruction and it connotes the place where those that had died were believed to be congregated. The word Sheol is believed by some to be an Assyro-Babylonian "loan word" but this has never been completely proven as true.

The question arises whether the Biblical concept is borrowed from the Assyrians or is an independent development from elements common to both and found in many primitive religions. Though most of the passages in which mention is made of Sheol or its synonyms are of exilic or post-exilic times, the latter view, according to which the Biblical concept of Sheol represents an independent evolution, is the more probable.

Most of this information was found in the 1906 Jewish Encyclopedia.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. Please see [What this site is about](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/what-christianity-stackexchange-is-and-more-importantly-what-it-isnt/) and [How this site is different](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites/1809#1809) to help you learn how the site works. Also see the [help] and take the [tour] to learn the site functions. I hope to see you post again soon.

Answer (score 3):

If by hell, you mean the final destruction of the wicked, it is first mentioned by Enoch as described by Jude

> And Enoch also, the seventh from Adam, prophesied of these, saying, Behold, the Lord cometh with ten thousands of his saints, to execute judgment upon all, and to convince all that are ungodly among them of all their ungodly deeds which they have ungodly committed, and of all their hard speeches which ungodly sinners have spoken against him. Jude 1:14 - 15

Comment: Where's the word "hell"? That could simply be (and likely is) physical destruction of those living on earth.

Comment: As I said, by hell if the OP meant the final destruction of the wicked, then this is the first instance chronologically.

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 you have to notice that the OP is not asking for the word but the concept

Comment: @C Rags: "Hell" isn't just "physical destruction." It's spiritual punishment/torment. But, then again, the OP hasn't even clarified what he means.

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 I think that the verse in Jude is talking about Spiritual and Physical Destruction - The term Execute in the verse I think is about the final reward given to the just and the unjust, which is represented in the parable of the goats and the lambs. If the OP clarifies further and the Question takes a different route, I will modify or remove my answer. Thanks for pointing out though

Comment: As I understand it, Judaism does not (generally) accept the existence of hell, which means we should focus on the New Testament.

Comment: Not true at all @Dick Harfield.

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hell  "Early Judaism had no concept of Hell ... concept of an afterlife was introduced during the Hellenic period. Judaism does not have a specific doctrine about the afterlife, but it does have a mystical/Orthodox tradition of describing Gehenna [-] not Hell, but originally a grave and in later times a sort of Purgatory where one is judged based on one's life's deeds, or rather, where one becomes fully aware of one's own shortcomings and negative actions during one's life. "

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 http://www.myjewishlearning.com/beliefs/Theology/Afterlife_and_Messiah/Life_After_Death/Heaven_and_Hell.shtml "several biblical references to a place called Sheol...where human beings descend after death... in Sheol, the deceased, although cut off from God and humankind, live on in some shadowy state of existence ... (setting precedents for later Jewish and Christian ideas of an underground hell) there is generally no concept of judgment or reward and punishment attached to it... insist that all of the dead go down to Sheol, whether good or evil, rich or poor, slave or free man

Comment: Jews believe in Gehinnom, which is the equivalent of "Hell."

Comment: Enoch is problemmatic, because it is a canonical reference to an extrabibilcal work.

Comment: @AffableGeek I believe Jude was inspired. If Jude quotes an extra canonical verse then it must be correct

Comment: OneFace - If that were true, Enoch would have been included in the Canon. Enoch is not considered "Biblical". Also, at a minimum, Gehenna - a fiery place of torment. There are references to this in the OT that are chronologically earlier than Enoch. However the OP makes it clear that he equates Sheol, Gehenna and Hades as hell, so the earliest reference is in Genesis for the purposes of this question. @DickHarfield - Jewish culture did have a belief in Hell during the post-exilic period when Enoch was written. During the formation of the Hebrew Canon is when hell was rejected, but this was AD.

Comment: @JamesShewey Agree. In fact I often have friendly arguments with Jews who believe that nothing has ever changed and therefore Jews never believed in hell (a place of punishment).  It seems to have entered Judaism from Zoroastrianism (along with heaven) but was rejected by later Jews - in my view before the Christian Era. Before this was sheol. Gehinnom was originally a real place outside Jerusalem, and some writings might have referred to this in an allegorical sense.

Comment: @JamesShewey are you suggesting Jude has lied? I don't know nor do I care to know where Jude quoted it from. Just the fact that Jude says this validates it for me. I believe "each" word of God is true. Maybe he quoted it from book of Enoch or perhaps he had some other source of which we are not aware. Either way I don't care. Jude says Enoch said it, then I totally agree with him and say "Enoch" said it. It is as simple as that.

Comment: No, I am not. I am suggesting Jude had it wrong and that Jude is not the first mention of hell. You are using the book of Enoch to say that Enoch said it first, but the OP specifically asks "Chronologically, when was the concept of Hell first mentioned **in the Bible**. Therefore, the book of Enoch is disqualified. Jude however is not. Despite this, there are texts which are chronologically older than Jude which reference hell (Sheol) earlier than Enoch. Enoch is a post-exilic pseudoepigraphical work (that is - a work attributed to Enoch that was really written 500BC or so).

Comment: The fact that Jude quotes 1 Enoch, which is a post-exilic pseudoepigraphical work is one reason why Luther had serious reservations about it and almost did not include it in the [Luther Canon](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/45727/14525)

Comment: @JamesShewey I found an article which dealt with this issue and I agree with its conclusion. https://www.christiancourier.com/articles/562-did-jude-quote-from-the-book-of-enoch. I don't know why we assume Jude quoted from the Book of Enoch when he could have written it originally through inspiration.

Comment: That is totally ungermane to the point. The question by the OP is "when is hell *first* mentioned *in the bible.* Chronologically speaking, Jude is after dozens of other references. The only way this helps is if 1) it was actually written by Enoch 2) 1 Enoch is part of the Biblical Canon. Unless 1 and 2 are true, then this reference is not the first.

Answer (score 2):

If I can understand the question correctly, you are asking for when was the concept of hell came into being in the bible.

I would suggest it came into being after the fall of satan and his followers.
Matthew 25:41 - King James Version
41 Then shall he say also unto them on the left hand, Depart from me, ye cursed, into everlasting fire, prepared for the devil and his angels:

The scripture clearly states as everlasting fire was prepared for the devil and his angels and not for humans. The scriptures also mentions that it's not God's will that his creation (humans) have everlasting life look at John 3:16 
Hell is for real and it's all over the Holy Bible, The word “hell” appears 54 times in the Holy Bible.
Reality of Hell:

- Matthew 8:12, 22:13, 24:51, 25:30, 13:28 There is darkness, weeping
  and gashing of teeth
- 2 Samuel 22:6, Psalm 18:5 There are sorrows in hell
- Job 11:8 Hell is deep
- Psalm 86:13 Lowest hell
- Psalm 116:3 There is pain in hell
- James 3:6 Your tongue is set on fire in hell
- Isaiah 33:10-17 There is a devouring fire, and everlasting burning
- Isaiah 66:24 worms never die and fire not quenched
- Matthew 25:41 Everlasting Fire
- Revelation 14:9-12, 20:10 You are tormented with fire and brimstone
  in God’s presence
- Revelation 21:8 It is a lake of fire and that is the second
  death

*A flood of false doctrine has lately broken in upon us. Men are beginning to tell us “that God is too merciful to punish souls for ever...that all mankind, however wicked and ungodly...will sooner or later be saved.” We are to embrace what is called “kinder theology,” and treat hell as a pagan fable... This question lies at the very foundation of the whole Gospel. The moral attributes of God, His justice, His holiness, His purity, are all involved in it. The Scripture has spoken plainly and fully on the subject of hell... If words mean anything, there is such a place as hell. If texts are to be interpreted fairly, there are those who will be cast into it... The same Bible which teaches that God in mercy and compassion sent Christ to die for sinners, does also teach that God hates sin, and must from His very nature punish all who cleave to sin or refuse the salvation He has provided. -- J.C. Ryle (1816-1900).*

If you are looking for merely the oldest chronological reference, Evangelicals in particular tend to consider Job to be the book in the Bible that refers to the oldest time period post-Genesis.  (This is due to a seeming lack of reference to Torah code) Job would thus be the "oldest" reference to hell.

Comment: According to [Strong's Concordance](http://biblehub.com/hebrew/7585.htm) there are 66 references to Sheol alone - not including Gehenna and Hades. The fall of Satan is never actually recorded in the Bible.