# History of the formation of the Biblical canon. Searching for accessible bibliographical references

Tags: bible, history, early-church, reference-request, canon

I am interested in finding bibliographical references narrating the formation of the Biblical canon in the first 5 centuries of the Christian era that are:

1. Academic books or articles written by authorities on the subject. Books and articles are preferable to websites. [This answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/86304/10672) to [another question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/86302/what-is-the-history-of-the-canon-of-the-bible-in-terms-of-66-or-73-books-cathol) does not address my question.
2. Preferably in the English language.
3. Preferably of an introductory nature. But I am willing to accept those of a non-introductory nature.
4. Preferably written in the 20th or 21st century.
5. Rich in archeological references.
6. Preferably historiographically critical (but not an essential requirement).

Comment: Everything written by Gary Habermas should suffice.

Comment: Also the book I don't have enough faith to be an atheist.

Comment: Or you could just go to Cambridge or Oxford study for 6 - 12 years to become a textual critic and make your own mind up.

Comment: Or you could go to the John Rylands museum in Manchester and view the oldest piece of New Testament in existence that is housed there with your own eyes. If it is on permanent display, not sure if it is. If archeology is your thing.

Answer (score 3):

- [The Old Testament Canon of the New Testament Church](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1606082493), by Protestant scholar Roger Beckwith [2008]. A fairly standard text that lays the groundwork from a Protestant perspective.
- [Why Catholic Bibles Are Bigger](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0998839914), by Catholic scholar Gary Michuta [2017]. Fantastic resource, 678 references (which are all either other scholars, or direct references to ancient literature and archeological finds). Digs into where Beckwith's work falls short and the difficult questions it insufficiently answered, the situation with Rabbi Akiba and the Bar Kokba revolt and its influence on canon, the changes in our understanding based on recent research on Dead Sea Scrolls, etc.
- [The Canon Debate: On the Origins and Formation of the Bible](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565635175), by numerous scholars compiled together [2002]. Great to get a sense of what's still in discussion, see what threads are left that need to be unraveled, many fantastic articles in here.
- [The Biblical Canon Lists from Early Christianity: Texts and Analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0198838891), by Protestant scholars Edmond Gallagher and John Meade [2019]. Another excellent resource, tons of leads to jump off into for further analysis if desired.

Answer (score 2):

The standard starting place for canonical studies in the NT is Metzger:

- [The Canon of the New Testament](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/the-canon-of-the-new-testament-9780198269540?cc=us&lang=en&)

In my own journey, the next place I stopped was Michael J. Kruger:

[The Question of Canon](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17861711-the-question-of-canon)

[Canon Article](https://tyndalebulletin.org/article/29324.pdf)

Also, note that much of Kruger's teaching can be accessed in audio/visual format from his seminary's website:

[NT canon lectures](https://subsplash.com/reformtheosem/learn-about-rts/ms/+xjduvb5)

Another resource would be Dr. Kloha's lectures on NT canon formation:

[Lay Bible Institute: Which Jesus](https://scholar.csl.edu/lbiwhichjesus/)

This is not a hard copy or article. But in these lectures, Kloha does interact extensively with primary sources, giving you examples of other books to read to grow in your studies.

Answer (score 2):

A few books to consider:

**The Canon of Scripture**
BY: F.F. BRUCE

**The Making of the New Testament: Origin, Collection, Text & Canon**
BY: ARTHUR G. PATZIA

**The Origin of the Bible, Updated Edition**
BY: F. F. BRUCE, J. I. PACKER, PHILIP W. COMFORT, CARL F. J. HENRY

Canonicity is only dealt in brief within the book “The Origin of the Bible”.

The other books are more comprehensive.

Either Amazon or Christianbook.com sells these.